# How to execute an .exe file in Progress OpenEdge

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Before I ask anything, let me tell you I have no experience whatsoever on Progress Openedge, but my company runs an application made in it and now I have to make some SOAP calls through it. So I figured, why not call an external script made in whatever language I deem fit?

But I can't even find how to run an external script through OpenEdge when I google for it. There's no examples anywhere, the documentation is long and confusing (for me at least). That brings me to this simple question:

How can I call an external script in Progress OpenEdge?

Comment: You can natively call SOAP services from Progress OpenEdge, no need for external scripts / exe's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try OS-COMMAND.

See [Progress Knowledge Base](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/16767), too.
And a [complete description on how to interact with your OS](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge112/oe112html/ABL/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Coding%20for%20Portability/CodingForPortability_Web_paper.057.3.html&single=true).

Comment: Thanks man. It's working as intended with: `OS-COMMAND NO-WAIT "C:\Test.exe"`

Comment: Yes of course, that was my intention but I had to wait 2 minutes don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up using this in a Windows application:

OS-COMMAND NO-CONSOLE "program_executed_here".

The lack of a "NO-WAIT" means my progress code waited until the command was finished (which I needed). The NO-CONSOLE keeps Progress from popping up an annoying console window after the OS command finishes running.